# used chmod wrongly to mess up copy rights. How to correct

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

I ran a `chmod` command like

```
chmod 644 dir/*
```

It seems to have worked for files in this directory, but files in all other sub-directories are now in some limbo state.

`ls -l dir/sub-dir` shows:

```
????????? ? ? ? ?            ? MyFiles.txt
```

Now I can copy any files from this directory into any other directory.
I get permission denied error.

How can I recover the permissions now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

- Chmod 755 dir/sub-dir and everything will be allright

Comment: 775 is a poor match for 644. Go with 755 instead. Other than that, this is a reasonable thing to try.

Comment: Ran this, it seem to have helped
find dir -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ';'

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant +x permission to all your subdirectories:

```
$ chmod +x $(ls dir/*/)
```

Or

```
$ chmod 755 $(ls dir/*/)
```

Will do the same thing